# Getting [$injector:unpr] error using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am getting this below error while click on link using Angular.js.

Error:

```
VM1186 angularjs.js:107 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/unpr?p0=UploadProvider%20%3C-%20Upload%20%3C-%20adminCatCategoryController
    at Error (native)
    at https://run.plnkr.co/8hsX4IhGSoTXwnkj/angularjs.js:6:416
    at https://run.plnkr.co/8hsX4IhGSoTXwnkj/angularjs.js:40:409
    at Object.d [as get] (https://run.plnkr.co/8hsX4IhGSoTXwnkj/angularjs.js:38:394)
    at https://run.plnkr.co/8hsX4IhGSoTXwnkj/angularjs.js:40:483
    at d (https://run.plnkr.co/8hsX4IhGSoTXwnkj/angularjs.js:38:394)
    at e (https://run.plnkr.co/8hsX4IhGSoTXwnkj/angularjs.js:39:161)
    at Object.instantiate (https://run.plnkr.co/8hsX4IhGSoTXwnkj/angularjs.js:39:310)
```

My code is below.

index.html:

```
<html ng-app="Spesh">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="angularjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="angularuirouter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="angularuibootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="loginRoute.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Test tab</h1>
    <div ui-view></div>
     <script src="adminController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="adminCategoryController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="adminCatCategoryController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="adminSubcatCategoryController.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

loginRoute.js:

```
var Admin = angular.module('Spesh', ['ui.router','ui.bootstrap']);
Admin.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$state = $state;
});
Admin.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
    .state('/', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'dashboard.html',
      controller: 'adminController'
    })
    .state('category', { /* This state defines the department management page */
        url: '/category',
        templateUrl: 'category.html',
        controller: 'adminCategoryController'
        })

        .state('category.cat', { /* This state defines the department management page */
        url: '/manage_category',
        templateUrl: 'manage_category.html',
        controller: 'adminCatCategoryController'
        })

        .state('category.subcat', { /* This state defines the department management page */
        url: '/manage_subcategory',
        templateUrl: 'manage_subcategory.html',
        controller: 'adminSubcatCategoryController'
        })
})
```

dashboard.html:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
     <li ng-class="{'active open': $state.includes('category')}"><a ui-sref="category.cat">Category</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="row" style="padding-top:120px;" ui-view>

</div>
```

Here when I am clicking on the `Category` link the above error is coming. My [Plunkr code is here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Rmz1rXlndvwu1Bt3CSvl?p=preview). How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Please provide your jsfiddle.

Comment: Where is `adminCatCategoryController` ?

Comment: something got messed with `UploadProvider`

Comment: Please check my updated post.

Comment: @Loading.. : Please check my post again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your plunker, the link "category/manage_category" will use the "adminCatCategoryController" controller . It has some code :

dashboard.controller('adminCatCategoryController',function($scope,$http,$location,$window,$state,**Upload,focusInputField**){
})

I can't find any file that define "Upload", "focusInputField" as service/factory or constant . So when you inject them in here, angular can't detect them and throw error.

Remove or defined them will resolve your problem.

Hope it helpful for you ! Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for detecting this type error.Its working now.